# SP_WhoIsActive - Writes Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was under the impression that the writes column in sp_whoisactive should show the number of writes applied to a table that SPID has completed.

However I am testing this and not getting the expected results.

I created a table with one column with datatype varchar(50)

Wrote a loop to insert into into the table every 5 seconds,  in a separate query window I am calling sp_whoIsActive,  but the number of writes is not matching?

```
DECLARE @Wait INT = 1
DECLARE @Counter INT = 0 
WHILE @wait = 1
        BEGIN



            INSERT INTO tomTest
                  ( Data )
            VALUES('tom' + LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(@Counter))))

            SELECT @Counter = @Counter + 1
            WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
        End
```

Thanks for your help

Tom

Comment: perhaps it would be useful to reference this: http://sqlblog.com/files/folders/release/tags/who+is+active/default.aspx and maybe https://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/

Comment: No idea what that sp is its 3rd party but views such as sys.dm_exec_sessions usually count in pages not rows or bytes

Answer (score 0):

From Adam Machanic when asked "What are the units on the various columns? For instance, used memory, reads, writes: pages, kb ...?"

Adam's Answer: Units are 8KB data pages unless otherwise specified.

[WhoIsActive V11.11](http://whoisactive.com)